# How to fix error: redefinition of '__kstrtab_sched_setscheduler_nocheck'

Tags: android, c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am compiling android kernel v3.10.108. I enabled kernel modules in defconfig and when tried to compile I came across this error. Here is the whole log on [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/vujakasugi.rb). Here is the [kernel source](https://github.com/theimpulson/android_kernel_asus_msm8916). I am not an expert in programming languages and I need help. Kindly also point out why the error occurred too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel source is actually [here](https://github.com/theimpulson/android_kernel_asus_msm8916). The error occurred because there were two commits that both added the line `EXPORT(sched_setscheduler_nocheck);` to the file "kernel/sched/core.c", leading to the redefinition errors. The commits are [here](https://github.com/theimpulson/android_kernel_asus_msm8916/commit/116f7291145efe8b302a09fecf1a36b11c047769#diff-641541f9c37c8e531edb52b0000d97d2) and [here](https://github.com/theimpulson/android_kernel_asus_msm8916/commit/f1d580a2ed1c9b3bc65c8b852ac282e45e75a41b#diff-641541f9c37c8e531edb52b0000d97d2).

The error occurred because whoever committed the changes did not check to make sure it still built properly when modules are enabled.

I suggest raising an [issue](https://github.com/theimpulson/android_kernel_asus_msm8916/issues) on github to report the error.

You can fix the problem locally by deleting one of the problematic `EXPORT(sched_setscheduler_nocheck);` lines in "kernel/sched/core.c" or by reverting the second one of those two git commits locally.

EDIT:

I never noticed there were two errors in your build log. The other one is due to two commits applied to "fs/fs_struct.c" [here](https://github.com/theimpulson/android_kernel_asus_msm8916/commit/6dc8a994491588bdcff14537424661d49fa46e7f#diff-3f36df752f42f36e2628598141e0268c) and [here](https://github.com/theimpulson/android_kernel_asus_msm8916/commit/c256b0d361c9c5eca33f118962f77f8b7dfe72a9#diff-3f36df752f42f36e2628598141e0268c).

EDIT 2

Subsequent linker errors are due to some things in the kernel .config being configured as modules (or possibly not configured at all) that are being linked to by other things configured as built-in.

Configure `CONFIG_HW_RANDOM_MSM=y` (not `=m`) to hopefully fix the "sensors_ssc.c" linker problems.

Configure `CONFIG_IPV6=y` (not `=m`) and `CONFIG_NF_DEFRAG_IPV6=y` (not `=m`) to hopefully fix the "ipc_router_security.c" linker problems.

Comment: I have reverted the commit (the second one). However the error still arises.

Comment: Sorry, I never noticed the other error. There is a similar problem with two commits applied to "fs/fs_struct.c". I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I removed that line and it is now fixed. Now, I get another error which I assume is related with module too. https://hastebin.com/nolufaraju.vbs  (In case you want, I can mark your answer as  accepted upto this point if you want, but I will be glad if you will help me more).

EDIT:

Comment: The subsequent errors look like there is something configured as "built-in" (`y`) in your kernel config that is trying to link to something configured as a "module" (`m`). That's probably due to some poorly defined dependencies in the set of `Kconfig` files altered by various kernel patches.

Comment: I added "EDIT 2" to hopefully fix the linker problems you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks. There were a lot of items not even present in my defconfig and hence during compilation they were automatically being treated as modules. I compared my defconfig with this one here https://github.com/FireLord1/android_kernel_lenovo_passion/blob/38215816f23e2ab779b27cdc2a44addc51342b21/arch/arm64/configs/p1a42-fk_defconfig while searching in log for items being treated as modules. I configured all of them and errors stopped. Thank you for helping me.